# Docker MySQL connection hangs after the webapp uses the DB

Tags: mysql, docker, timeout

I have a simple Docker MySQL startup as per the official readme.

I can successfully connect from the host

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -uroot -proot
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
[mysql promt appears]
```

I then deploy my webapp into Tomcat and  it works, connection to DB works fine and I can still connect to mysql from the host.

However, if I now stress the DB (the webapp does a fairly high number of read / write, but nothing that would justify breaking anything)
the connection to the docker mysql just stops (hangs)

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -uroot -proot
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
{And here it just hangs for ever}
```

From that point I can no longer reach the MySQL prompt and it 'looks' like there is a firwall that got activated on the docker and is blocking incoming connection.. (just a feeling)

I can perfectly `docker exec` inside the Docker MySQL and perfectly reach the MySQL prompt from within the container.....

What is happening? How can I debug this

Comment: Maybe you exceeded the maximum amount of active connections? I experienced the same problem with a Java webapp hosted on tomcat a few months ago. Check how many active connections is the max and then stay logged into a mysql terminal and keep track of the active connections to see if it does in fact exeed this maximum

Comment: That was my first thought But how would you explain that I'm able to mysql -u -p from within the container but it hangs from the host?
(Btw I checked and max conn = 151 and there is 10 active connections)

Comment: Did you find a solution @Marco?

Comment: No I haven't. I didn't try with the newer version of docker though